# RFID Reading Interval and SameID Reading Interval

Tags: rfid

I'm having a problem about the `Read Interval` of my `RFID Reader`. The `Read Interval` and `SameID interval` are all set in *x10ms* which is declared in `Byte`. In configuration the max ms i can set is `255 ms` and that is equal to *2,550 seconds*. Can someone help me? This is the screenshot of the configuration.

Please the piture:
[The SameID Interval in the form is in *s* but the max number is only 255](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPBfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is only the specification of the product you are using, and does not specify the behavior of the application program you make.

Applications can incorporate their own Same ID checks.

For example, when tag data is read from an RFID reader, it memorizes time and tag data pair in the application.
Every time the tag data is read, it compares it with the read data stored in the application, if there is the same tag data, compare it with the reading time, and if it is within the time specified yourself, read it later you can discard the data.

P.S.
You can also comment on the manufacturer and wait for it to be realized, or request and fund it to make a special product for you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I have an Application showing the time when the tag is detected by the RFID Reader.

So basically what i need to do is after the Application recorded the time when tag is inserted in database and then read interval is reached, It starts again to read the tag. Compare the time in database and the time when the tag is read again. If the range or interval is greater than (ex:) 10 seconds, read it later. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It is to emulate the behavior when the SameID interval parameter of the RFID reader supports up to your desired period. 
I do not speak English as my mother tongue, I am using Google translation, I think there is a wrong sentence, please ignore the details.